# Random Number Limiter

Tags: python

So I tried making a random number generator that never makes duplicates and gives the same amount of numbers.

The code gives me a duplicate and I can't seem to stop some duplicates to the duplicate stopper.

Heres the code:

```
import random
list=[]
a=0
for i in range(0,10):
    n=str(random.randint(0,10))
    if n==list:
        pass
    else:
        print(n)
        list+=n
print(f"list is {list}")
```

the bottom is for checking if the code work, but it didn't because it adds duplicates, and I don't know how to make a for loop redo.

Answer (score 3):

the random module already provide you with a function for that in [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

For example said you want 5 random number between 0-10

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(11),5)
[0, 2, 7, 4, 3]
>>> random.sample(range(11),5)
[7, 6, 4, 2, 3]
>>> random.sample(range(11),5)
[6, 10, 4, 3, 2]
>>> random.sample(range(11),5)
[10, 0, 5, 6, 4]
>>>
```

but if you want it the hard way, use a set that remove duplicates and in a loop check that you got the desire number of results

```
>>> uni=set()
>>> while len(uni)<5:
        uni.add(random.randint(0,10))

    
>>> uni
{1, 4, 5, 6, 8}
>>>
```

but remember to first check that the number of unique possible results is less that or equal to the number of result you want, or you would be stuck in an infinite loop

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you are asking for a list where the range of numbers is barely larger than the length of the list.  So create a list of those numbers and `shuffle` it, then dump the excess.

```
lst = [str(n) for n in range(11)]
random.shuffle(lst)
lst = lst[:10]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
arr=[]
a=0
for i in range(0,10):
    n=str(random.randint(0,10))
    # use n in arr to see if n is in the arr
    if n in arr:
        pass
    else:
        print(n)
        # do arr.append(n) instead of arr+=n
        arr.append(n)
print(f"list is {arr}")
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `list` as a variable name it will override the build in `list` use arr or some other name that makes sense.

```
import random

arr=[]
a=0
for i in range(0, 10):
    n=random.randint(0, 10)
    if n in arr:
        pass
    else:
        print(n)
        arr.append(n)
print(f"list is {arr}")
```

## Better approach

Instead of using `list` use `set` since you want **unique** values because searching in `list` every iteration will decrease efficiency of your program.

```
import random

arr = set()
for i in range(0, 10): 
    arr.add(random.randint(0, 10))

print(f"list is {arr}")
```

## One liner solution

```
import random

print(f"list is {set(random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(0, 10))}")
```

Comment: why a list comprehension like that? use the one liner solution you put right below or use the update method

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you were asking for a list that includes random numbers from 0 to 10 with the length of the list equalling 10.

```
import random
randomList=[]
listLength=10
lb = 0 #lower bound for random integer
ub = 10 #upper bound for random integer
while True:
    n = random.randint(lb, ub)
    if n not in randomList:
        randomList.append(n)
    if listLength == len(randomList):
        break
print(f"list is {randomList}")
```

I would recommend using a while loop instead of a for loop since you can never predict what the random is. Using a while loop and exiting only when the conditions of the list you described is more methodical. Also, don't use `list` as a variable since that is a builtin class and you never want to have variables named after builtins. You only use `+` to lists only when you are adding other lists as well as an extension. You can use append instead if you want to add on more items. I wouldn't suggest going for more complicated codes since for a python beginner, understanding the basics is more important than making the most simplified code.